# Why does it work with $scope but not with `this`?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I want to know why the following only works with the scripts 1 and 3 and not with the 2. I want to use this because in my project I can't use $scope.

Thank you!!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> <!--   -->
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Modelo</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
         Nombre: {{ name}}
         <script type="text/javascript">
         var app=angular.module("app",[]);
         function AppCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.name= "Bob";
         }
         </script>
      </div>
<br/>
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
         Nombre: {{ name }}
         <script type="text/javascript">
         var app= angular.module("app",[]);
            var MyCtrl = function() {
               this.name = 'Nico';
            }
            app.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);
         </script>
      </div>
<br/>
   <div ng-controller="Algo as and">
      Nombre: {{and.name}}
      <script type="text/javascript">
         //angular.controller('Algo',Algo);
         function Algo() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.name = "Nicolas";
         }
      </script>
   </div>

   </body>   
</html>
```

If it's hard to understand please tell me.

And forgive me for my English.

Comment: It works with that too, just define the controller as you have done for "script 3" as "MyCtrl as ctrl"

Comment: "script 3" only works because you are using the legacy angular version 1.2.19 here.  The use of `this` was revamped in angular 1.3, so in current iterations of angular, #3 won't work either.

Comment: Thank you! It was just that stupid thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-controller` uses constructor function of the controller. In 1st and 3rd cases, we have constructor functions to controllers. But in second case its just a variable. So, it will not work.

`ng-controller="myCtrl"` when you define something like this, angular tries to find the constructor function of the `myctrl`. If, `function myCtrl(){}` is there, it works fine. That is what happening in 1st and 3rd case.

The extra use of `$scope` than `this` is when there are event watchers. But we can avoid them. for more info https://johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/ You can get idea which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

To access `this` over `$scope`, you must use the [**controller as** syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example), which is what your third example does. But the usage may vary a little, see the doc link above for example code.

[This post](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) talks of the advantages of the controller as syntax in real development, you may want to take a look.